# Substring tries to process a wrong (negative) index

Tags: java, indexof

I have a snippet of code here that is giving me trouble:

```
    idIndex = panoBuffer.indexOf("\"photo_id\":");
    System.out.println(idIndex);
    photos[i].id = panoBuffer.substring(idIndex, panoBuffer.indexOf(','));
```

The middle line is for debug purposes. However, the output I get is as follows:

```
253
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -240
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at panoramio.Panoramio.jsonToArray(Panoramio.java:248)
at panoramio.Panoramio.main(Panoramio.java:83)
```

Why does it say -240 when clearly the index of what I require is 253?

Comment: What is the index of `,`? Did you check?

Comment: idIndex is larger (by 240) then panoBuffer.indexOf(',')

Comment: What is the value of `panoBuffer.length()`?

Comment: It seems I made a mistake as panoBuffer.indexOf(",") gets the first comma and the one I am trying to get is not the first occurence of the comma. However I tried to change it to panoBuffer.substring(idIndex).indexOf(',') but it still does not work. The length of panoBuffer is 8431.

Comment: If there are a lot of commas you can just find the right one yourself with a loop instead of using low-level String API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `panoBuffer` contains more than one comma, which perhaps leads to that you find a comma that comes before `idIndex`.

Try replacing
`panoBuffer.indexOf(',')` with `panoBuffer.indexOf(',', idIndex+1)` instead, this way you will find the first comma that comes *after* `idIndex`.

You should also make sure to check that you actually do find a value by verifying that the result of `indexOf` is greater than `-1` as specified in the documentation for [String#indexOf(int,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: I need the string between idIndex and "," where comma is after the idIndex. I realized I made a mistake where I was getting the first comma of the whole panoBuffer but the comma I am trying to reach is neither first nor last of its kind.

Comment: @Praxbyr my solution will do just that, it will find the first comma that comes after `idIndex` (which may be last, though)

Comment: Thank you! It seems you update your answer before I submitted my reply. It works now!